# In assembler, why does the use of registers differ between addition and subtraction?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have a very basic doubt here. I have two very simple C codes and their assembly codes:

program 1:

```
main()

{

    int temp1, temp2, temp3;
    char temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9;
    temp1 = 5;
    temp1 = 9 - temp1;
}
```

Assembly:

```
   0x080483b4 <+0>: push   ebp    
   0x080483b5 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp    
   0x080483b7 <+3>: sub    esp,0x20    
   0x080483ba <+6>: mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x5    
   0x080483c1 <+13>:    mov    eax,0x9    
   0x080483c6 <+18>:    sub    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]    
   0x080483c9 <+21>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax    
   0x080483cc <+24>:    leave      
   0x080483cd <+25>:    ret
```

Program 2:

```
main()    
{    
    int temp1, temp2, temp3;
    char temp5, temp6, temp7, temp8, temp9;
    temp1 = 5;
    temp1 = 9 + temp1;    
}
```

Assembly:

```
   0x080483b4 <+0>: push   ebp    
   0x080483b5 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp    
   0x080483b7 <+3>: sub    esp,0x20    
   0x080483ba <+6>: mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x5    
   0x080483c1 <+13>:    add    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x9    
   0x080483c5 <+17>:    leave      
   0x080483c6 <+18>:    ret
```

Why in the case of subtraction, eax register need to be used and not in the case of addition. Can't it be like:

```
0x080483c1 <+13>:   sub    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x9
```

instead of -

```
0x080483c1 <+13>:   mov    eax,0x9

0x080483c6 <+18>:   sub    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
```

Comment: no. In the C code, you are subtracting a variable from 9. In your assembly you should be subtracting a register from 9, which is that of the assembly code and not sub DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x9
. On the assembly code, eax is subtracted with 5. In your premise, you are subtracting 5 with 9.

Comment: did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: @ninjalj: Obviously he didn't. Because otherwise the whole thing would surely have been optimized to a single `ret`.

Comment: @celtschk: Sure. My point was that noone should care about unoptimized compiler output, it's supposed to be massaged later by the optimizer, so can be quite crappy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing because addition is commutative (*A + B == B + A*), whereas subtraction is not (*A - B != B - A*).  Because of this the addition of `9 + temp1` is the same as `temp1 + 9`, hence the simpler assembler sequence. `9 - temp1` involves creating a temporary variable.

Comment: you meant commutative: associative means *(A + B) + C == A + (B + C)*

Comment: I did indeed Cristoph, two decades since my last math class and two many beers between this and then.

Answer (score 2):

`temp1 = 9 - temp1;` is the same as `temp1 = - temp1 + 9;`. This carries out 2 operations:

1. Negate `temp1`
2. Do the addition

`eax` is used as the temporary location to save the middle value.

In the addition case, there's no "middle value", the operation can be done directly.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what is being asked in the question. Also, the assembly code does not contain a negation instruction.

Answer (score 2):

The actual reason for the observed behaviour has been implied by the other answers, but never explicitly mentioned:

Common instruction sets feature ops for the following computations:

```
%register := %register + $immediate [1]
%register := %register - $immediate [2]
```

Because of commutativity, `[1]` can also be used to compute

```
%register := $immediate + %register
```

However, a dedicated op for

```
%register := $immediate - %register
```

is in general not available, which means it has to be emulated, eg by the sequence

```
%temp     := %register
%register := $immediate
%register := %register - %temp
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is a lack of symmetry in the x86 instruction set, which doesn't contain an instruction for subtracting a register from a constant.

For example, the ARM instruction set contains the `RSB` (Reverse SuBtract) instruction exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Actually the ARM instruction set is the non symmetrical in this case - it lacks a (of course useless) `reverse add` instruction, where x86 in this case is symmetrical - it lacks both instructions, the useful reverse subtract and the useless reverse addition. The deeper reason for this (and the need for an reverse sub) is of course the lack of symmetry in the subtraction - it's not commutative.

Comment: The symmetry in this case is between the two ways to do subtraction.

Comment: Incidentally, PIC brand microcontrollers have a 'subtract W from constant' instruction, but no 'subtract constant from W register', since the latter instruction could be simulated by adding 256-constant.